# JSon content Deserialization to DataTable wrongly parsing DataType

Tags: c#, datatable, json.net

I have a webapi which returns json serialized DataTable result set, on the client side, when i try to deserialize the same, Value of the column will be converted from float to int. Can anyone suggest me on how to solve this issue. I went through many posts but didnt find the working solution.

Below is a sample snippet to repro the issue using console app.

```
string jsonString = "[{\"Column1\":1.0,\"Column2\":0.0,\"Column3\":1.0}]";
DataTable dt=  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString);
```

now accessing dt.Rows[0][0] will return 1 instead of 1.0.

If there are any other suggestions on different way to pass datatable from WebApi is also acceptable. below is the web api code snippet

```
    [HttpPost]         
    public IHttpActionResult GetData(string some parameters)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //some datatable 
       Ok(dt);
    }
```

Comment: Not leaving this as an answer, because it's not clear if the problem you're trying to solve *requires* JSON.  One option is to use XML serializers built into C#.

If JSON is required, the Newtonsoft libraries support [de]serialization of `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the Json Serializer settings to handle floats...

```
string jsonString = "[{\"Column1\":1.0,\"Column2\":0.0,\"Column3\":1.0}]";

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal
        };
```

and supply the settings when deserialising...

```
var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString, settings);
```

I would add that it may not be a great idea to use DataTable in this way - it's worth bearing in mind that any meta-data on the source DataTable, such as keys and constraints will be lost when deserialising at the other end.

Comment: yes, datatable should not be used, but it is for our test project. And thanks, Settings works fine.